# ANT Design Form.List wont remove element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

My plan is to build a step-by-step from where users can add more sections as needed to a form. This plan is divided into several files to achieve the result, including a parent, a child, and the Quill editor component. I've followed the examples found in the ANT Design website: https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items but failed to replicate the example.

This is the setup for the React-Quill Editor component:

```
//texteditorsimple.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactQuill, {Quill} from 'react-quill';
import MagicUrl from 'quill-magic-url';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

//registering magic url module
Quill.register('modules/magicUrl', MagicUrl);

const modules = {
    toolbar: [
        ...
    clipboard: {
        ...
    },
    magicUrl: true,
};

const formats = [
    'list',
    'bullet',
    'link',
];

const TextEditorSimple = ({ value, onChange, placeholder }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <ReactQuill
                theme="snow"
                value={value || ''}
                modules={modules}
                formats={formats}
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder={placeholder} >
            </ReactQuill>
            <div id='counter'></div>
        </>
    )
}
export default TextEditorSimple;
```

This is the Parent component:

```
//parent.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
...
import Child from '../child';

const Parent = () => {
    const [ formValue2, setFormValue2 ] = useState([]);

    const deleteY = (data) => {
        const newArrayFormValue = formValue2.filter(obj => !obj.name.includes(data));
        setFormValue2(newArrayFormValue);
    }
    return (
        <Row justify='center' align="top" style={{ padding: 10}}>
            <Col>
                <Child deleteX={deleteY} fields={formValue2} onChange={(newFields) => {setFormValue2(newFields)}}/>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}
export default Parent;
```

And this is the Child component:

```
//child.js
import React from 'react';
...
import TextEditorSimple from './texteditorsimple';

const Child = ({fields, onChange, deleteX}) => {
    <Row justify='start' align="top">
        <Col xs={24} style={{ padding: 10}}>
            <h2>Pengenalan & Langkah-langkah</h2>
            <Form 
                fields={fields}
                name="dynamic_form_nest_item" 
                onFinish={onFinish} 
                autoComplete="off"
                onFieldsChange={(_,allFields) =>{
                    onChange(allFields);
                }} >
                <Form.List name="tutorial" style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                    <>
                        {fields.map(({ index, key, name, fieldKey, ...restField }) => (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <Row>
                                {
                                    name === 0 ?
                                    <Col xs={24} style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                                        <Form.Item
                                        {...restField}
                                        label='Pengenalan'
                                        name={[name, 'pengenalan']}
                                        fieldKey={[fieldKey, 'pengenalan']}
                                        >
                                            <TextEditorSimple/>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    :
                                    <Col xs={24} md={16} style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                                        <Form.Item
                                        {...restField}
                                        label={'Langkah '+ name}
                                        name={[name, 'langkah'+name]}
                                        fieldKey={[fieldKey, 'langkah'+name]}
                                        >
                                            <TextEditorSimple/>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                }
                                <Col xs={24} md={8} style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                                {
                                    name === 0 ?
                                    ''
                                    :
                                    <Space align="start">
                                        <Form.Item
                                        {...restField}
                                        name={[name, 'image'+name]}
                                        fieldKey={[fieldKey, 'image'+name]}
                                        valuePropName="fileList"
                                        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
                                        extra="Muat naik satu (1) imej/tangkap layar">
                                            <Upload 
                                                name="image" 
                                                customRequest={dummyRequest} 
                                                listType="picture-card" 
                                                maxCount={1} >
                                                {/* <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Muat naik imej/ tangkap layar</Button> */}
                                                {uploadButton}
                                            </Upload>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                        <DeleteOutlined onClick={() => { remove(name); }} style={{ color: 'red'}}/>
                                    </Space>
                                }
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <Divider/>
                        </div>
                        ))}
                        <Form.Item>
                            <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                                Tambah Langkah
                            </Button>
                        </Form.Item>
                    </>
                    )}
                </Form.List>
            </Form>
        </Col>
    </Row>
}
export default Child;
```

I'm trying to catch the changes made on the `Form.List` 'tutorial' (add, delete) in the `Child` and uplift the value to the `Parent` and store them in the state. But the deletion somehow not reflected in the UI, as the element that should have been deleted persisted on page. Tried to manually change the state through poorly coded `deleteX` and `deleteY` function, but not successful.

The GIF showing the error can be viewed here: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/HsIjHuckIflqOr3gOO

Comment: Could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for this?